# Android device monitor not launching (Adb connection Error:EOF)

Tags: android, adb, genymotion

When click the Android device monitor it not launching.
But all the functionality of android studio was fine.

**My device details,**

> My operating system - ubuntu 14 (64bit)
>
> My android studio version - 1.5.1
>
> my genymotion version - 2.6.0

**My error log,**

> [ 245019]   WARN -            #com.android.ddmlib - Adb connection
>    Error:EOF
>   [ 245023]   WARN -            #com.android.ddmlib -
>   Connection attempts: 1

What I have tried,

**Attempt 1:**

I have changed monitor.ini file in tools/lib/monitor-x86 folder as below,

-Xms256m

-Xmx512m

**Attempt 2:**

```
Open your cmd .Go to Platform-tools/ path
Run the cmd like : adb kill-server
Then : adb start-server
```

**Attempt 3:**

Remove my all avds & restart again

**Attempt 4:**
In my genymotion settings set like this
[image]

**Attempt 5:**

> Update the latest version of android sdk tools & platform tools
>
> My current sdk tools 24.4.1 & sdk platform tools 23.1.0

I search for this problem more than 3 days in google & I tried more than 100 links.But sadly my bad luck still now not get solution.

anybody help me.

Comment: Have you tried launching the `monitor` command?

Comment: @cuihtlauac monitor command also not working

Comment: Then, I'd try `strace`

Comment: @cuihtlauac I enter this command, it shows list of commands.. what is next step

Comment: Can't explain `strace` in a SO comment :-) basically it will tell you what are the system calls which are performed by `monitor`. Look for errors in the log. Google around for tips on using `strace`.

Comment: yes I got this error...execve("/usr/sbin/monitor", ["monitor"], [/* 69 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                              = 0x7efc66f4f000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7efc64fc7000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/android-studio/bin/tls/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/opt/android-studio/bin/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffebabc36f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: It should not look for `libc.6.0` in `/opt/android-studio/bin/tls`, something is wrong there.